# Exchange values in pandas with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df such as:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore
scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0
scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   500 20  222 487 1.e-16  94.0
scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7
```

and I would like to change the values in `df.qstart` and `ds.qend` if `df.qstart>df.qstart`

Here it would be:

```
qseqid  sseqid  pident  length  mismatch    gapopen qstart  qend    sstart  send    evalue  bitscore
    scaffold_1  test    25.5    337 166 9   2   20  27  310 1.0e-16 94.0
    scaffold_1  tes2    27.0    278 163 9   20 500  222 487 1.e-16  94.0
    scaffold_1  tes4    35.5    166 93  2   3   10  63  227 2.e-15  89.7
```

as you can see 500 was put in the place of 20
Thank for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the values and assign them back:

```
import numpy as np
df[['qstart', 'qend']] = np.sort(df[['qstart', 'qend']].values, axis=1)
```